# Infopath 2013 load form for next list item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, list-form

I am stuck on a small feature of an InfoPath form which is the default edit form for a SharePoint List.

They basically want to be able to use the View item form to be able to scroll through the SharePoint List items. I have an InfoPath form web part on a separate page, where they want a sort of "Slideshow" function.

Currently, I have a previous and next button with rules to "set id" of the item to +1 or -1 depending on if they want to view the form of the previous or next item. Then, the button queries based on the new updated ID.

However, I cannot get the next or previous fields to load. I've searched Infopath Dev and other sites but cannot find any related info, so if anyone has information related to this functionality, please let me know.

Comment: using dataconnection on hit of button have you tried to read the data and set it back to the fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as explained in the article - http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2010/infopath-2010-previous-next-navigation-sharepoint-list.htm

You can create a solution that combines a hidden field, formulas, and conditional formatting to be able to filter data from a secondary data source for a SharePoint list and thereby create previous next navigation functionality in InfoPath 2010.

Comment: I've tried this solution and step 15, where it says On the Specify Filter Conditions dialog box, select The expression from the first drop-down list box and then change the expression in the text box from:

`xdXDocument:get-DOM()/my:myFields/my:position = ""`

to

`number(xdXDocument:get-DOM()/my:myFields/my:position)`                    This part is different for infopath 2013 so it did not work for me